# How to fill textboxes based from combobox

Tags: javascript, php, combobox, textbox

I'm still learning Web programming and I'm having a problem on how I'm going to fill my 3 textBoxes based from chosen option in combobox.

I tried using php inside javascript but it seems I'm not doing it right. What I'm trying to do is to load the name, age and address of of a user based from the chosen option combobox so that I can update their data.

```
  <?php
    include("myconnection.php");
    session_start();
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
        <script>

                    function listUpdate()
                    {
                        var ddl=document.getElementById("userlist");
                        var selectedOption=ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex];
                        var nameNya=selectedOption.getAttribute("value");
                        console.log(nameNya);

                        var tb1=document.getElementById("nameid");
                        var tb2=document.getElementById("ageid");
                        var tb3=document.getElementById("addressid");
                        tb1.value="gago";

                        <?php
                        /*

                            $sql="SELECT * from users WHERE fullname='nameNya'";
                            mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                            $nameNyaa=$_POST['nameNya'];
                            echo $nameNyaa;*/

                        ?>

                    }

                </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form action="updateuserprocess.php" method="POST">


                <h1>UPDATE USER</h1>
                <?php
                    $sql="SELECT * from users";
                    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                    echo '<select id="userlist" onChange="return listUpdate()">';
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                    echo "<option value='".$row[3]."'>".$row[3]."</option>";
                    }
                    echo '</select>';


                ?>

    <br>            


                <label>Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" id="nameid"><br>
                <label>Age: </label> 
                <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="" id="ageid"/><br>


<label>Address: </label>
            <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="" id="addressid"/><br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK"/>
            <button type="submit" formaction="/myhome.php">Back</button>
        </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))

    {
        include("updateuserprocess.php");

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
$('#mycomboboxID').change(function() {
    var combobox_value = $('#mycomboboxID').val();

    $('#myInput1').val('First');
    $('#myInput2').val('Second');
    $('#myInput3').val('Third');
}
```

You can do if statement inside as well,
and remember you need a jquery extension for this to work